# Set value of hidden column cell DGV

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a DGV which displays the attachments from a certain template read form a DB and added buttons to move up/down a selected row. Each attachment has a "sortOrder" property which gets updated each time one of the buttons has been pressed. To fill the DGV correctly, I need the attachments ID, but don't want it do be displayed, hence this column .Visible = False.

My problem is on this line: `dgvAttachmentRight.CurrentCell = dgvAttachmentRight.Rows(iIndex).Cells(0)`

I know that I can't set a value from a hidden cell, but since I'm still a beginner, I don't know any other way how I could do this. Does anyone have an idea? Beneath is the code for the moveUP-Method, moveDown looks basically the same. 
Thanks a lot for your answers.

```
    Dim iIndex As Integer = dgvAttachmentRight.CurrentRow.Index - 1

    Dim id1 As Integer = dgvAttachmentRight.Rows(iIndex).Cells(0).Value
    Attachment.GetAttachmentById(id1).IncreaseSortOrder(tmpTemplate)

    dgvAttachmentRight.Rows(iIndex + 1).Selected = True

    Dim id2 As Integer = dgvAttachmentRight.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
    Attachment.GetAttachmentById(id2).DecreaseSortOrder(tmpTemplate)
    LoadAttachmentData()

    dgvAttachmentRight.CurrentCell = dgvAttachmentRight.Rows(iIndex).Cells(0)
    dgvAttachmentRight.Rows(iIndex).Selected = True
    selectionChanged()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got the solution. It's so simple...

Changed `dgvAttachmentRight.CurrentCell = dgvAttachmentRight.Rows(iIndex).Cells(0)`

to `dgvAttachmentRight.CurrentCell = dgvAttachmentRight.Rows(iIndex).Cells(1)`